# Serve markdown with Caddy2

Tags: markdown, caddy, caddyfile

I want to serve a single markdown file with Caddy v2, rendered as html. The old Caddy v1 had the `markdown` directive, which is gone. Instead I found the `template` directive, but it does not render the markdown files served.

Caddyfile

```
:80
templates
encode zstd gzip
root * /static  
file_server browse
```

Starting caddy with

```
docker run -it --rm --name caddy -p 8080:80 -v $PWD/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile -v $PWD/static:/static -v caddy_data:/data caddy:2.1.1-alpine
```

I was only able to manage to serve a html file, that contained `{{markdown "Some _markdown_ text"}}` to be rendered, but not a whole `index.md`.

How to serve simple markdown files with Caddy v2, or is it not longer possible?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://caddy.community/t/markdown-support-in-v2/6984 this should do:

---

You can do it a few ways. The easiest way is your first example:

```
{{markdown "whole Markdown file here"}}
```

You can also bring in a file by name:

```
{{include "file.md" | markdown}}
```

Here’s another example, it’s how we serve the docs on the Caddy site: https://github.com/caddyserver/website/blob/master/src/docs/index.html